# how to know your user is done with wallet-recharge or not in instamojo?

Tags: payment-gateway, instamojo

I am integrating my website with instamojo and its backend is java.
Their is wallet recharge functionality in it.
I want to know when user is done with recharging his wallet with specific amount.
So that i can update my database.

Their are several options on their API like payment link and Add product.

In this case which one should i use.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can do this by having webhook url.

we have to create REST service in our application so that instamojo and hit this service when transaction is successful.

It should be provided in merchant panel while configuring payment links.